# .htaccess code for Desktop ->Mobile | Mobile -> Desktop?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have searched stackoverflow for whole day, found code only working for redirecting Desktop ->Mobile, sometimes it works, sometimes it not:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/m/ [L,R=302]
```

Anyway, i can not find any working solution for redirecting Mobile -> Desktop.

Can anybody share working solution of .htaccess for redirection `https://www.example.com` ---> `https://www.example.com/m/` for Mobile devices and `https://www.example.com/m/` ---> `https://www.example.com/` for Desktop users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these 2 redirect rules for mobile -> desktop redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MOBILE:1]

# desktop -> mobile
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:MOBILE} =1
RewriteRule ^ /m%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# mobile -> desktop
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^desktop [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:MOBILE} ^$
RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks, it does Mobile -> Desktop redirection. Redirecting of Desktop -> Mobile does not works. It always redirects to ```https://www.example.com/``` on both PC and mobile,  no matter i am visiting ```https://www.example.com/``` or ```https://www.example.com/m/```.

Comment: Result is the same. I am testing it on desktop and smartphone Chrome, every time clearing cookies, history etc.

Comment: ok can you try my update rules with caching disabled

Comment: I always purge cloudflare's cache twice :) Now ve have error on Desktop ->Mobile: m/m/m/m/m/m/m/. Mobile->Desktop is working

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the problem.
Found that Cloudflare has mobile redirect option by itself.
So made a mobile site on subdomain, enabled mobile redirect on CF to that subdomain.
Enabled “Cache everything” on both root domain and subdomain.
Removed redirect rules from .htaccess.
Now i have normal TTFB and mobile traffic redirection is working.
Only Desktop->Mobile - will be good as is it.